# Proof: continuous function is bounded

Tags: real-analysis

I've seen some proofs for this Lemma and wanted to know what's wrong with my take.

Lemma. Let $a < b$ be real numbers, and let $f : [a, b] → R$ be a function continuous on $[a, b]$. Then $f$ is a bounded function.

Proof:
Because we know $f$ is continuous, for a given $\epsilon$ we can find $\delta$ such as $|x-x_0|< \delta \Rightarrow |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$.
I proceeded to use triangle inequality so: $|f(x)| - |f(x_0)| \le |f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon$.
Then $|f(x)| - |f(x_0)| < \epsilon$. And finally assert that $\epsilon + |f(x_0)|= M$ so that $|f(x)|< M$

Hope I am using MathJax the right way.
Thanks :)

Edit: I forgot to add that $x_0 \in [a,b]$

Comment: Note that your proof does not use anywhere that the domain of $f$ is a closed interval $[a,b]$.  The same proof would "work" to show that the function $f(x) = x$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$ which is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what $x_0$ is. If $x_0$ is an arbitrary point of $[a,b]$, then what you have proved is that near $x_0$, $f$ is bounded. It is not automatic that it follows from that that $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$.

Besides, the same argument who work on *any* subset of $\Bbb R$, but, say, $\frac1x$ is *un*bounded on $(0,1]$.

Comment: Yep. I meant exactly what you are saying. That x0 belongs to [a,b]. Your last paragraph cleared my mind though. Gracias José!